# How to make parallel cudaMalloc fast?

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

When allocating a lot of memory on 4 distinct *NVIDIA V100 GPUs*, I observe the following behavior with regards to parallelization via OpenMP:

Using the `#pragma omp parallel for` directive, and therefore making the `cudaMalloc` calls on each GPU in parallel, results in the same performance as doing it completely serial. This is tested and the same effect validated on two HPC systems: *IBM Power AC922* and an *AWS EC2 p3dn.24xlarge*. (The numbers are obtained on the Power machine.)

```
./test 4000000000

# serial

GPU 0: 0.472018550
GPU 1: 0.325776811
GPU 2: 0.334342752
GPU 3: 0.337432169
total: 1.469773541

# parallel

GPU 0: 1.199741600
GPU 2: 1.200597044
GPU 3: 1.200619017
GPU 1: 1.482700315
total: 1.493352924
```

How can I make the parallelization faster?

Here is my code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  size_t num_elements = std::stoull(argv[1]);
  
  auto t0s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    auto t0is = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cudaSetDevice(i);
    int* ptr;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr, sizeof(int) * num_elements);

    auto t1is = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "GPU " << i << ": " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9)
            << std::chrono::duration<double>(t1is - t0is).count() << std::endl;
  }

  auto t1s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "total: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9)
            << std::chrono::duration<double>(t1s - t0s).count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

You can compile the microbenchmark with:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -Xcompiler -fopenmp -O3 test.cu -o test
```

- I also tried `std::thread` instead of OpenMP with the same results.

Comment: I think its unlikely that you'll find a way to make this faster.  `cudaMalloc` affects the address maps of all GPUs visible to the CUDA runtime, so there is serialization happening in the CUDA runtime.  What you should do is design your application in a way such that this doesn't matter.  A single `cudaMalloc` takes a few hundred milliseconds at the most (not including CUDA lazy initialization), so it should not be a big limiter.  If you have to do it over and over, reuse allocations or use a pool allocator. (For example, TensorFlow uses a pool allocator.)

Comment: Rapids has a [memory manager](https://github.com/rapidsai/rmm) that can do pool allocations for you.

Comment: Re "making the cudaMalloc calls on each GPU in parallel": A `cudaMalloc` call is pretty much all host work, with the GPU(s) performing no work. Generally speaking, and independent of the use of GPUs, memory allocators usually work in multiple layers, and many designs are essentially single-threaded (at least at the bottom-most layer).

Comment: nowadays, the way to do this is via stream-oriented memory allocators using CUDA memory pools.